# Does ST_Intersection work in 3D?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am using "ST_Intersection" between two 3D lines which I believe do not intersect, but the result gives me their intersection.

```
SELECT ST_ASText(ST_Intersection(
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING( 1 1 1, 5 5 1)'),
        ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING( 4 1 10, 1 5 10)'
      )));
```

---

results in:

> POINT Z (2.71428571428571 2.71428571428571 5.5)

Comment: Would http://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html handle it better?

Comment: Dear @ mapBaker, I just use "ST_3DIntersection" but It make this error: 
ERROR: function st_3dintersection(geometry, geometry) does not exist

Comment: see the answer below regarding availability of this function...

Answer (score 5):

ST_3DIntersection is available only via the SFCGAL extension.  Unfortunately only windows (PostGIS 2.2 experimental) and Ubuntu (via docker ) have it at the moment, so most likely you'd have to compile PostGIS yourself to use it.  It would be useful to know the OS you are on.

PostGIS windows 2.2 experimental binaries have SFCGAL and can be downloaded here:
http://postgis.net/windows_downloads  (these get built by the PostGIS windows build-bot so get updated whenever the PostGIS 2.2 code base changes)

I should add that after you compile with SFCGAL support, if you are on PostGIS 2.1, you need to run the sfcgal.sql file.  For PostGIS 2.2 you can do

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
CREATE EXTENSION sfcgal;
ALTER DATABASE your_db_here 
  SET postgis.backend = sfcgal;
```

The setting the postgis.backend is not necessary to use the ST_3DIntersection, but it will force functions like ST_3DIntersects to use the sfcgal implementation instead of the PostGIS implementation.  (The SFCGAL one understands volumes and TINS (more is coming in 2.2 -- I'll be updating the SFCGAL library to include the new volume functions, the ST_3DUnion function and couple of others as soon as it's committed into PostGIS).

Might want to check SFCGAL site too to see what's coming: http://oslandia.github.io/SFCGAL/

Comment: I have Win64-bit.
So, how can I add it on my own computer?

Comment: The PostGIS 2.2 epxerimental windows builds have SFCGAL -  go here:  http://postgis.net/windows_downloads  (I should note we have for 9.3 and 9.4 (both 32-bit and 64-bit) but not for 9.2 . Instructions are at the bottom of that page after you've copied over all the files from the zip to your PostgreSQL install.  I amended my answer a bit.

Comment: I already download " postgis-2.1.5-5" from :
http://winnie.postgis.net/download/windows/pg94/buildbot/
But, when I run "CREATE EXTENSION sfcgal; " I get this error:
ERROR: could not open extension control file "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.4/share/extension/sfcgal.control": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01

Comment: I download some useful binary files and add on share/extension, but it say follow error yet:
ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.2": No such file or directory
SQL state: 58P01
how can I fix?

Comment: Hmm that usually means the postgis-2.2.dll is not in the lib folder.  Which particular zip did you download.  Did you make sure to copy the lib files into your program files\postgresql install folder?  you should be able to just copy all the files in the zip and overwrite whatever you have in your PostgreSQL install.  The folder structure is setup the same.

Comment: Dear @LR1234567, Tnx for your useful help.

Comment: Reza are you all set or still having problems?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `ST_3DIntersects`. Which provides you the correct result on your sample query in your question:

`SELECT ST_ASText(ST_3DIntersection(
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING( 1 1 1, 5 5 1)'),
  ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING( 4 1 10, 1 5 10)'
    )));`

Have a look at the link below:
It is available from **PostGIS 2.0.0** onwards.
https://postgis.net/docs/ST_3DIntersects.html

---

**Result:**
As you can see from the result, It is empty.

> 1 | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY